# ngbTabTitle with button causes redirect

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I have the following:

```
<ng-template ngbTabTitle>
  <span title="{{p.name}}">#{{pi+1}}</span>
  <button type="..." (click)="removePackage($event, pi)">R</button>
</ng-template>
```

But when the user clicks the button, it redirects the user back to the root route (the home route).
In the removePackage() method, I have attempted to stop propagation using event.stopPropagation(), but that doesn't seem to have helped.

Can someone tell me how to add a button (or *anything* clickable) in the tab title, without re-directing the user?

Answer (score 1):

Call `preventDefault()` on the event.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vxewgs?file=app%2Ftabset-basic.ts)